# Deep link issue on iOS (Universal Link)

Tags: uber-api, deeplink

I have created several Uber deep links via the Uber deep link generator and the links work fine on my Android device. However, when I access the links on my iOS, the Uber app comes on but the dropoff address doesn't come up. Instead, it shows me an empty search bar and I have to type in the address again. I proceeded to re-arrange my client_id to the front as shown but it still yield the same results.

https://m.uber.com/ul/?client_id=jZywlUAYPjYl3uRcFPquz0e_wJqLSmPZ&dropoff[formatted_address]=No.%2047%2C%20Beian%20Road%2C%20Zhongshan%20District%2C%20Taipei%20City%2C%2010491&action=setPickup&pickup=my_location

Does anyone know what I did wrong or what else should I do for this to work on both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that you can check :

1. A minimum OS level of iOS 9 is required for Universal Links support. So please make sure your iOS version is up to date.
2. Can you try to add to your Universal Link : &d‌ropoff[latitude]=xx.xxx&dropoff[longi‌tude]=yy.yyy

UPDATE:
I have tested following Universal Link on my iPhone and it is working:

https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=Rd3a2B9JITPWPLPzmvXXXXXXX&pickup[latitude]=25.0791848&pickup[longitude]=121.5265924&dropoff[latitude]=25.0777658&dropoff[longitude]=121.5283466&dropoff[nickname]=No.%2047%2C%20Beian%20Road%2C%20Zhongshan%20District%2C%20Taipei%20City%2C%2010491

Or

https://m.uber.com/ul/?action=setPickup&client_id=Rd3a2B9JITPWPLPzmvXXXXXXX&pickup[latitude]=25.0791848&pickup[longitude]=121.5265924&dropoff[latitude]=25.0777658&dropoff[longitude]=121.5283466&dropoff[formatted_address]=No.%2047%2C%20Beian%20Road%2C%20Zhongshan%20District%2C%20Taipei%20City%2C%2010491

I have added pick up location because my real location is not the location you specified - but  pickup=my_loc‌ation is also fine if it is not against Uber terms related to pickup and destination distance.  Also instead of "dropoff[formatted_address]" try to use "dropoff[nickname]"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.

1. Yes it is all updated. Both App and iOS
2. I tried adding it but the results is the same.